# scrollable linearlayout with weights bigger than screen in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am trying to create a vertical linearlayout with weights that has a size bigger than the screen. Let's say 2x the size of the screen. In order for this to work I would obviously need to be able to scroll through it. Unfortunately I can't figure out a way to do this. I tried using the layout weights, and setting the weight sum as half of the actual sum of the weights of all components (so if all components weights sum is 20 I set the weight sum as 10) and managed to make it work but unfortunately the scrolling is not working anymore for some reason.

Is there anything that I am missing?

this is the code that makes the linearlayout twice as big as the screen but the scroll is not working:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <EditText android:id="@+id/id1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/id2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your comment, here is a programmatic way of achieving what you're looking for. I do not believe there is a way to accomplish this in pure layout XML.

Layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/id1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#DCDCDC"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="ONE ONE ONE"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="45sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/id2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#AAAAAA"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TWO TWO TWO"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="45sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/id3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#777777"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="THREE THREE THREE"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="45sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      // Get display size -- API L13 and up. Otherwise use getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
      Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
      Point size = new Point();
      display.getSize(size);


      // You want size to be 50% per EditText, so divide available height by 2.
      // Note: this is absolute height, does not take into consideration window decoration!
      int editTextHeight = size.y / 2;

      // Get a handle to your EditTexts
      EditText t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id1);
      EditText t2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id2);
      EditText t3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id3);

      // Set height to 50% of screen size each
      t1.setHeight(editTextHeight);
      t2.setHeight(editTextHeight);
      t3.setHeight(editTextHeight);
}
```

That'll do it. End result:

[image: EditText 50% screen height]
[image: EditText 50% screen height]
[image: EditText 50% screen height]

Comment: thanks for the reply. I knew how to do this programatically, but still definitely worth the bounty even just for confirming that it cannot be done in pure xml

Answer (score 3):

You declared height of your `LinearLayout`  "`match_parent`" that is equal to its parents height. It will never scroll as long as the content is bigger then `ScrollView`. First of all you have to give a fixed height like (50dp) or `wrap_content` or you have to set Its height programmatically(like 2x screen height as you mention).

`weightSum` and `weight` will always force your items to fit in your `LinearLayouts` current size so try not to use it.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your use of `layout_weight` and `weightSum` is invalid. It's important to remember that `android:layout_weight` can only use the **remaining space available** in the view; anything exceeding that boundary is automatically cropped.

Therefore, in your example, your first `EditText` is taking up the entirety of the screen, and your second one is entirely excluded from the view. Because the second `EditText` is cropped, the `LinearLayout` has taken the entire screen and there's nothing for the `ScrollView` to do.

I'm not entirely sure what your end goal is; are you trying to have text inputs that grow with user entry, and the `ScrollView` handles the overflow?

If so, this will work:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#DCDCDC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ONE ONE ONE"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="45sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/id2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#AAAAAA"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TWO TWO TWO"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="45sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I've included some basic background colors so that you can see where each item begins & ends in layout preview. Typing in the first `EditText` will correctly push the second one down, producing a scroll bar.

Also note that you should use `sp` instead of `dp` for `textSize` values.

Edit: I should also note, for clarification, that `weightSum` will also *take away* space when necessary. To test this, set the `weightSum` of your `LinearLayout` to 2, and then add `android:layout_weight="1"` to each of the `EditText` controls. The end result will be a 50/50 split when the view loads, and then as you start typing in the first control, the 2nd space will shrink accordingly. Adding text to the second control will result in a scrollbar appearing.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the reply. Basically, in one sentence, a good example of what I am trying to achieve is have 3 textviews, each one with size 1/2 of the screen size. That means that the 2 would appear in the screen and the third one would only appear when scrolling down.

Comment: There's no way to do that in pure XML; you'd have to measure the screen and set the view height in code. I can provide a sample for you.

Comment: @shijuB that doesn't work, please see my answer above; doing what you said results in the the layout filling the viewport without scrolling. Add on a 3rd `EditText` and it will be unreachable off-screen.

Comment: @shijuB Just to reiterate, that doesn't work. All that will do is fill the viewport at 50% per EditText and not allow him to scroll.