# How to merge two views in Android

Tags: scrollview, android, achartengine

My requirement is to display a pie chart and a bar graph in a page in Android. To do so, I am generating two views using the following:-

1. ChartFactory.getBarChartView(getActivity(), buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer, Type.DEFAULT)
2. ChartFactory.getPieChartView(getActivity(), categorySeries, defaultRenderer)

I am able to display them individually. But I need to display both the views in a single page with scrolling. How can I achieve this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a layout like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Save the result of your calls ChartFactory.getBarChartView() and ChartFactory.getPieChartView() in 2 variables graph1 and graph2

Then in code add the 2 charts to the layout

```
LinearLayout view1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.view1);
LinearLayout view2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.view2);

view1.removeAllViews();
view1.addView(graph1);

view2.removeAllViews();
view2.addView(graph2);
```

In my solution both charts are shown on one page. If you want each chart to fill one screen maybe this can help:
[scrollable linearlayout with weights bigger than screen in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033126/scrollable-linearlayout-with-weights-bigger-than-screen-in-android)