# add items to scrollview below screen?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have a layout that I need to fill the screen and depending on the contents of the layout, I may need to add terms and conditions below it.  I'm using a scrollview and the fillViewport attribute allows me to get the main layout to fill nicely, but when I add the terms, it resizes everything.

Is there a way to get items added to a scrollview to populate below a specific point without resizing everything above it?  If not, is there a workaround that can accomplish the same thing?

Layout and visual example:

in this layout, the last item has visibility set to 'GONE', so the 3 textviews fill the screen...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sampleItem1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:text="SAMPLE VIEW 1"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sampleItem2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="SAMPLE VIEW 2"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sampleItem3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:text="SAMPLE VIEW 3"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/termsAndConditions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="VIEW THAT MAY OR MAY NOT BE ADDED"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

but if I set 'termsAndConditions' visibility to 'VISIBLE' the other 3 views resize... Can I stop that?

[image: with 'termsAndConditions' set to GONE:]

[image: with 'termsAndConditions' set to VISIBLE:]

My goal is to have that green view populate beneath the bottom margin of the screen and the user can scroll to it as everything is encased in a scrollview

Comment: please include your layout in the ques and how you fill it

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat it's for work, So I can't show the actual layout, I'll put together an example, though.  give me 5 minutes

Comment: Added sample code and images.  Thank you

Comment: Great, so you want the position of the `TextView` being reserved either if it's not exist? or you want to make the images fills the screen forever? but then where will you display your text ?

Comment: I want the first screenshot to be the way it looks, regardless if the terms are added.  if the terms are added, they should be added beneath the bottom margin of the screen. the upper most parent view is a scrollview so if the terms are added, the user can scroll down to them.

Comment: the actual view is very nice looking and the terms throw it off.  They're there out of contractual obligation and we'd prefer they don't interfere with the user's experience

Comment: So, you want the terms to be included in the Scrolling and the user has to scroll in order to see it ?

Comment: that's exactly what we want

Comment: Great, I'll have a look at the code and see if i can help

Comment: I found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033126/scrollable-linearlayout-with-weights-bigger-than-screen-in-android

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to add a `weight_sum = 3` to the parent layout of the `TextViews`, then make the `TextView` of **terms** `layout_height="0dp"` in order to add a weight to it, and add the weight to it as you want let's say "**0.3**", So, it will be like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sampleItem1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:text="SAMPLE VIEW 1"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sampleItem2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="SAMPLE VIEW 2"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sampleItem3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:text="SAMPLE VIEW 3"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/termsAndConditions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="VIEW THAT MAY OR MAY NOT BE ADDED"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: looks right in the xml preview screen.  going to take me a minute to change our actual layout.  Working on it now, just need a few

Comment: didn't work, unfortunately.  My guess is because the first layout is filling all available space due to the parent's weightSum.  doesn't even scroll

Comment: We just found a working solution, but I don't think it's the BEST solution, so I'm not going to accept it as the answer in hopes of getting a better one.  Posting it now.

Comment: well, I'll see if I could overcome that and will inform you, thanks

Answer (score 0):

What we did to make this work was set the visibility of terms to GONE, then in the fragment's onCreateView, we did this:

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.viewParent);
parent.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        parent.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    } else {
                        parent.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    }

                    int height = parent.getHeight();
                    parent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height));
                    termsAndConditions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            } );
```

so with terms set to GONE, we measured the parents height, then replaced it's MATCH_PARENT height property with that measurement, then set terms to visible, which populated below everything else because we had set the static height.

In the back of my mind, this feels like using a cannon to kill a mosquito, so if there's any other solutions, I'm open.

Comment: Wow! Turns out, I need to do exactly the same in my app, but still don't know how. This solution above is kind of a hack. Have you found anything more viable for the problem?